# Referencing keys in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var foo = { someKey: "someValue" };
var bar = "someKey";
```

How do I get the value "someValue" using foo and bar? OK, the PHP equivalent:

```
$foo = array("someKey" => "someValue");
$bar = "someKey";
print $foo[$bar]; // someValue
```

So... I'm looking for the JS equivalent for the above, except I don't wanna use a JS array. Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

> foo[bar]

You use *square brackets* to reference string key values.

`foo.someKey` is equal to `foo["someKey"]`

Comment: I ticked your answer cos you were 1 minute faster.

Answer (score 2):

foo[bar] should do it. In js objects are basically glorified hashtables.