# Use variable as object index

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I'm trying to find how to pass a variable as object index, for example:

```
function createObject(index,value){
  var data = {index:value};
  console.log(data);
}

createObject('hello','world');

//result Object { index="world"} instead of Object { "hello"="world"}
```

I couldn't find this specific answer so far..

Thanks!

Comment: how would like to be?  Object { index="world"} or Object { "hello"="world"}?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing keys in a Javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518971/referencing-keys-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `object[index]` notation:

```
function createObject(index,value){
    var data = {};
    data[index] = value;
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood what you want that's the code

```
function createObject(value){
  var data = {'index':value};
  console.log(data);
}

createObject('world');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createObject(index, value) {
    var data = { 'index' : value };
    console.log(data);
}

createObject('hello', 'world');
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this question, JavaScript has added some improvements since it was asked/answered:

```js
const BRAND = Symbol('_brand_');
const my_var = 'hello';

const foo = {
  [BRAND]: 'bar',
  [my_var]: 'world'
};

console.log(foo[BRAND]); // -> 'bar'
console.log(foo.hello);  // -> 'world'
```